# Find $a(n)$ with generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find $a(n)$ with generating functions of recurrence: 
\begin{cases} a(1)=3 \;,\;a(2)=10 \\ a(n)=6a(n-1)-3a(n-2)\end{cases}
I went till :
$h(x)-10x-3=6xh(x)-3x^2h(x)$

but I'm stuck in the part of partial fractions. Please show your work till the end of solution.

Comment: Your $6x h(x)$ is not correct.

Comment: beacuse 6a(n-1)

Comment: is euqal to sum of 6a(n-1)x^n then 6x*(x0+x1x+...)=6xh(x)

Comment: h(x)=a0+a1x+a2x^2+a3x^3+...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

$$h(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}a(n)x^{n-1}=a(1)+a(2)x+a(3)x^2+\cdots$$

is the generating function for $a(n)$, we have

$$\begin{align*}
a(n)&=6a(n-1)-3a(n-2)\\[1ex]
\sum_{n\ge3}a(n)x^{n-1}&=6\sum_{n\ge3}a(n-1)x^{n-1}-3\sum_{n\ge3}a(n-2)x^{n-1}\\[1ex]
&=6x\sum_{n\ge3}a(n-1)x^{n-2}-3x^2\sum_{n\ge3}a(n-2)x^{n-3}\\[1ex]
&=6x\sum_{n\ge2}a(n)x^{n-1}-3x^2\sum_{n\ge1}a(n)x^{n-1}\\[1ex]
h(x)-a(2)x-a(1)&=6x\big(h(x)-a(1)\big)-3x^2h(x)\\[1ex]
(1-6x+3x^2)h(x)&=3-8x\\[1ex]
h(x)&=\frac{3-8x}{1-6x+3x^2}
\end{align*}$$

For the partial fraction decomposition, you can use the quadratic formula to show that the denominator has roots at $x=1\pm\sqrt{\frac23}$.

Then

$$\begin{align*}
h(x)&=\frac{\theta_1}{x-\left(1-\sqrt{\frac23}\right)}+\frac{\theta_2}{x-\left(1+\sqrt{\frac23}\right)}\\[1ex]
3-8x&=\theta_1\left(x-\left(1+\sqrt{\frac23}\right)\right)+\theta_2\left(x-\left(1-\sqrt{\frac23}\right)\right)
\end{align*}$$

Using the ["cover-up" method](http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes03/h.pdf), we have

$$x=1-\sqrt{\frac23}\implies\theta_1=\frac52\sqrt{\frac32}-4$$

$$x=1+\sqrt{\frac23}\implies\theta_2=-\frac52\sqrt{\frac32}-4$$

Comment: what about if 1-6x+3x^2 cannot be factored? Should I have to find x1x2 from quadratic equation then A/x1 +B/x2 = 3-8x/1-6x+3x^2 - is this way correct?

Comment: And h(x) is OGF that means h(x)=a0+a1x^1+...+anx^n

Comment: The nice thing about quadratics is that they are easy to factorize. I'll update my answer with the working of the decomposition in a moment. Also, the fact that the GF here doesn't start with $a(0)$ is simply because that value is not provided. We can "continue" the sequence by solving for $a(0)=\frac83$, but I don't see a particular reason for doing that.

Comment: ooo thanks you gave me a lesson that when we dont have a(0) I can do h(x) as you said... Thanks11